# I want to send POST details from getPlainBody data

Tags: google-apps-script

Peace
I get data in the command:

```
function myFunction() {
  let from = GmailApp.search('xxx');
  var body = lastMessage.getPlainBody()
  Logger.log(body)
}
```

How can I send a POST to a particular address?

Because of my lesser English will help detail and examples

I'm sorry for the way I speak, I'm just translating

Thank you

Comment: What is "POST"?

Comment: Did you mean [send](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app?hl=en#sendEmail(String,String,String))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send a POST request using UrlFetchApp.fetch(). See more information below.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).